# React-router : render is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react.js. I upgraded [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) from `v0.13` to `v1.0.2`.

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/832c42946c874fe56ffde0066b1088054311cb98/CHANGES.md), I replaced

```
Router.run(routes, function(Root){
    React.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

with

```
render(<Router routes={routes}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I get an error saying render is not a function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look at [one of the examples](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/832c42946c874fe56ffde0066b1088054311cb98/examples/active-links/app.js#L2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An import:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
```

Then you should be good.